# Polynomial of degree $2$ that has smallest distance from $e^x$ in $L^2([-1,1])$

Tags: real-analysis

What is a direct approach (that does not involve manually calculating minima) to find polynomial of degree $2$ that has smallest distance from $e^x$ in $L^2([-1,1])$?

Comment: Without specialising the degree, there is no best polynomial. If the degree is given, you have to expand $e^x$ into a series of chebyshev-polynomials to find the best approximation.

Comment: @Peter Added. I'm not familiar with Chebyshev-polynomials; what would the construction be?

Comment: The first chebyshev-polynomials are $T_0(x)=1$ , $T_1(x)=x$ , $T_2(x)=2x^2-1$

Comment: I am not an expert either for tchebyshev-polynomials. Look at Wikipedia or mathworld under "checbychev-polynomials" or "best-approximations". This should be helpful. Loosely speaking, you must calculate some definite integrals to get the coefficients of the expansion

Comment: You are asking to minimize distance in $L^2([-1,1])$, which is equvialent to finding a polynomial $f(x)$ to minimize the expression 
$\| e^x - f(x) \|_2 = \left( \int_{-1}^1 (e^x - f(x))^2 dx \right)^{1/2}$
The correct procedure is given in  robojon's answer. If you want to use orthonormal polynomials, you should use [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) instead of Chebyshev polynomials. Chebyshev's polynomial is probably more useful for minimization with respect to [sup norm/uniform norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** find the minimum of
$$
f(a,b,c)=\int_{-1}^1\left(ax^2+bx+c-e^x\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

---

**Answer to the New Question**

Find an orthonormal basis for $L^2[-1,1]$. Start with
$$
e_0=\sqrt{\frac12}
$$
Then use [Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to get
$$
e_1=\sqrt{\frac32}\,x
$$
and
$$
e_2=\sqrt{\frac58}\left(3x^2-1\right)
$$
Now, just project $e^x$ onto the subspace of $L^2$ spanned by these three basis vectors.
$$
\begin{align}
e_0\left\langle e_0,e^x\right\rangle+e_1\left\langle e_1,e^x\right\rangle+e_2\left\langle e_2,e^x\right\rangle
&=\frac{e^2-1}{2e}+\frac{3x}e+\frac{5\left(e^2-7\right)\left(3x^2-1\right)}{4e}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac3{4e}\left(5\!\left(e^2-7\right)x^2+4\,x+\left(11-e^2\right)\right)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: To be honest, this is just the definition. The problem is how to do it in a direct way.

Comment: @user393664, the minimum is easily calculable. See my answer.

Comment: @user393664: You might want to modify the question to ask that. The question you asked is "how do I find the polynomial..."

Comment: @robjohn Done. Thanks.

Comment: @user393664: Appended my answer.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment? The question was changed, and so I modified my answer in response.